# Table floating and textbox issue

Tags: html, css

I am having a hard time trying to fix two tables side-by-side. I tried `float:left` for both of them but still not working. Also, i'm not able to reduce the second and third column's width. Can someone help me out here with the code given:

```
<div class="variablecosts">
        <!-- VARIABLE COSTS FORM STARTS HERE  -->
        <form style="float:left;display:inline-block;" action="post" name="varcosts">
            <table id = "variable_cost" border="1" >
                <tr>
                    <th>RESP</th>
                    <th>MCSS</th>
                    <th>COH</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>3R00 (Mech. Services)</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="" /> </td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="" /> </td> 
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <th>Total</th>
                    <th>some value </th>
                    <th>some value </th>    
                </tr>
            </table>
            </form>




            <form style="float:left;display:inline-block;" action="post" name="varcosts">
            <table id = "variable_cost"  border="1" >
                <tr>
                    <th style="width:50px;">RESP</th>
                    <th style="width:50px;">MCSS</th>
                    <th style="width:50px;">COH</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="width:50px;">3R00 (Mech. Services)</td>
                    <td style="width:50px;"><input type="text" name="" /> </td>
                    <td style="width:50px;"><input type="text" name="" /> </td> 
                </tr>

            </table>


</form>
    </div>
```

And the CSS is here:

```
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
table {
    font-size: inherit;
    white-space: nowrap;
    table-layout:fixed;
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
}
.loginTable{
    margin: 40px auto;
    background: #fff;
    width: 450px;
}
.loginTable tbody{
    border:2px solid #d5d5d5;

}
.loginTable tbody, tr, th, td{
    padding:10px;
}
.loginTable select, input, textarea {
    width:200px;    
}
.mmrTable{
    text-align:left;
    width: 590px;
}

    .variablecosts{
        width:400px;
    }
    #variable_cost{
        white-space: normal;
        table-layout: fixed;
        width:450px;
        float:left;
        border: 1px solid #ddd;
    }
    #variance_cost tbody,tr,th{
        width:75px;
    }
    #variable_cost input,text{
        width: 70px;
    }
    #variable_cost tbody,tr,td{
        width: 80px;
    }
```

Comment: Code in your question please.

Comment: Ummm...your fiddle link doesnt work. Can you also include some HTML/CSS in your question?

Comment: roughly copied the related CSS to table in here. Hope that is all that is concerned with the question.

Answer (score 1):

You forms need to be no larger than 50% in width (including any side padding, margin and borders)

Your 2nd and third columns won't shrink because you have inputs in them so you need to make the size of the inputs smaller and then you will be able to set the size of the columns to a size larger than the inputs (table cells use width like a min-width when it comes to non-breaking elements)

Once you have fixed these two things it should solve your problems